# MVC View renders as plain HTML when server validation fails

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

[image]Basically I am building a complicated MVC 5 Razor form using bootstrap tabs, partial views and jquery validation.

On both my Create and Edit views, if one required field for example is not valid on an active tab, the form can be posted - of course it fails the server side validation and then instead to return back the page properly through the view, 
all I get is a plain white HTML page with all the html code in it !

URL seems ok.

Of course I am doing the following on my HttpPost :

```
return View(Form);
```

Could you please advise me, why I am getting back a white html page and how can I improve my client side validation to validate the full form ?

Thank you in advance !

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Create(CcFormVM Form, Guid LoanId)
    {

        var findLoan = (from s in olm.LoanRequests
                        where s.LoanRequestId == LoanId
                        select s).FirstOrDefault();

        var configCCFORM = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<CcFormVM, CcForm>().BeforeMap((s, d) => d.FormStatus = Enum.FormStatus.Submitted).ForMember(x => x.ID, opt => opt.Ignore()).ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<CcFormVM, CcBorrower>().BeforeMap((s, d) => d.LoanId = LoanId).BeforeMap((s, d) => d.ID = 0).BeforeMap((s, d) => d.BorrowerName = findLoan.BorrowerAccounts.CompanyName).ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<CcFormVM, CcLoanRequest>().ReverseMap();
        });


        IMapper CCFORMmapper = configCCFORM.CreateMapper();

        var dest1 = CCFORMmapper.Map<CcFormVM, CcForm>(Form);
        var dest2 = CCFORMmapper.Map<CcFormVM, CcBorrower>(Form);
        var dest3 = CCFORMmapper.Map<CcFormVM, CcLoanRequest>(Form);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.CcForms.Add(dest1);
            dest2.BorrowerName = findLoan.BorrowerAccounts.CompanyName;
            db.CcBorrowers.Add(dest2);
            db.CcLoanRequests.Add(dest3);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }


        ViewBag.BorrowerName = Form.BorrowerName;           
        ViewBag.LoanId = LoanId;
        ViewBag.CountryID = new SelectList(db.Countries, "ID", "CountryName", Form.CountryID);
        ViewBag.GoverningLawID = new SelectList(db.GoverningLaws, "ID", "GoverningLawName", Form.GoverningLawID);
        ViewBag.LanguageID = new SelectList(db.Languages, "ID", "LanguageName", Form.LanguageID);            
        ViewBag.FacilityTypeList = new SelectList(db.FacilityTypes, "ID", "FacilityTypeName", Form.FacilityTypeID);
        ViewBag.NaceCodeList = new SelectList(db.NaceCodes, "ID", "Description", Form.NaceCodeID);


        return View(Form);
    }
```

Comment: Do you literally get the html code in your browser? Can you show the controller action for this form post?

Comment: Can you also include controller method and html view in your post?

Comment: It might be an issue with your controller method. update the controller Action in question

Comment: Hi , I have included more information

Comment: Also include your form html

Comment: @Wizeman1986 - I would suggest opening up Fiddler to see what HTTP status code is returned from your controller action? I'm guessing it's not a 200?

Comment: its a 200  and returns the html page from my screen shot

Comment: @Wizeman1986 gotcha - are you using JS or an actual form submission to post to your controller?

Comment: Actual submit like this :  <input type="submit" value="Submit Final" class="btn btn-default" />

Comment: Well, since you're using plain form submit (not AJAX), are you submit from a partial view in tabbed base view? The partial view seems holding keys to point out your issue.